# Programs for Purple Comet Math Meet

Tags: math-software

I am going to be participating in the high school division of the [Purple Comet Math Meet](http://purplecomet.org/welcome/practice). Since computers are allowed to be used on the competition, I was wondering if anyone can recommend software/programs that I can use to solve these types of questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Google Chrome and access to Math Stackexchange ;)

Comment: [Matlab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matlab), [Mathematica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica) or [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)).

Comment: @metacompactness Is it possible to learn the python necessary to do these types of questions by tomorrow?

Comment: @user140900 Do you have any programming experience? If not, just use a scientific calculator.

Comment: @metacompactness I am intermediate in Java.

Comment: @user140900 So you can use Java since the problems don't require the use of advanced mathematical features (like bessel functions, integral equations...).

Comment: @metacompactness If I have a system of two equations and I want to find all possible values of three unknowns, how do I do this in Mathematica?

Comment: @user140900 Like [that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7Ba+x+%2B+b+y+%3D%3D+1%2C+x+-+y+%3D%3D+2%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+y%7D%5D).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about how these kind of contests work. But seeing the problems for last years, these came to mind:

1. Some kind of good calculator, always useful.
2. If you have some programming knowledge, and you are allowed to use it in the competition, then for sure I would have my IDE of choice. Some of the questions are programmable (for example, the counting questions, although I am sure it's not the idea, you can bruteforce without much trouble in Java or C++ o whatever you like.)